# Returning a part of model in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Sorry, i couldn't title my question well.

The point is, I have a model say `model1` defined in Entity Framework for Web API in C#.NET.

say the model has the following fields

`field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`

A web api method return this model. I call the web api from a web application and an android application, everything works fine, no problem.

Issue is, in my android application, i need only the field1, field2 & field3.

I want to use the same model but return only required fields and ignore the rest to optimize the data consumption on the mobile device.

Do I have a way to do it. Yes, I can create another model `model2` with only the required fields and assign the values to model2 and return it, but i don't want to create another model.

reason for not creating another model is in the live application I have almost
47 fields and various methods will return only a subset of these fields and one has to return all the 47 of them. So, maintenance becomes an issue.

Hope I made sense in my requirement, would request some help.

thank you.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://tostring.it/2012/07/18/customize-json-result-in-web-api/ specifically the part about null handling, if you configure it this way all the null parameters will be ignored and not sent, so if you retrieve the needed fields and left the others on null you will receive only the non-null fields.

Comment: although this is not the required answer, i learnt some new cool stuff from the link.

Comment: well, that does exactly what you asked, return only the needed fields without creating a secondary model, if that's not what you wanted then I did not understood your question.

Comment: BTW, the word you are looking for to describe this kind of thing is called `Projection`. The LINQ `.Select` extension method does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create another reduced model, then one option is for your web api controller actions to return object types.

And during the final return statement in your controller, you could just do an anonymous projection from the model1 class, and return back the selected fields only.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
 public object SomeGetAction()
 {
   var model1 = GetModel1();

   if (android)
   {
    // send back partial payload
    return new { field1 = model1.field1, field3 = model1.field3 }; 
   }

   // for clients needing full payload.
   return model1;
 }
}
```

this ensures the data you sent across the wire is reduced. but please note that you would still be extracting all the fields from the database or whatever is your backend source.

the other option is to return Dictionary
either ways, you lose strong typing of the field names, without a strong model2.

Comment: `return new { field1 = model1.field1, field3 = model1.field3 };` will do the trick for me. thank you